# Intercept cancel button press on ConnectivityManger requestNetwork new dialog, API 29

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-connectivitymanager

I'm using the ConnectivityManger's `requestNetwork` API to programmatically connect to a specific network specified by a `NetworkRequest` object provided as first parameter. I also provide a `NetworkCallback` to receive notifications related to the status of the request.

Starting from API 29, the OS is showing a Dialog (`NetworkRequestDialogFragment`) where the user can select a network from the list or cancel the action.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-bootstrap), the NetworkCallback's `onUnavailable` method is invoked when the user clicks on the dialog's cancel button but also in case of connection failure.

Is there any advanced mechanisms to distinguish between these two scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

`onUnavailable()` is only called in two scenarios:

1. The user manually cancels the request
2. The second case requires you to use a timeout within your request. If that's the case, running out of time will trigger `onUnavailable()` as well.

As for your questions, I don't think there's either a way of intercepting neither this Dialog or the second Dialog you get once `onUnavailable()` is triggered stating that there was an error -- I've been looking all over the place for something like this too. :/